# structure with nested maps golang

Tags: struct, go, maps

Hi I'm new to go and was trying to figure out how maps work.
I have made up a little test program and can't seem to get it to work.
What I'm doing wrong?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Stats struct {
    cnt      int
    category map[string]Events
}

type Events struct {
    cnt   int
    event map[string]Event
}

type Event struct {
    value int64
}

func main() {

    stats := new(Stats)
    stats.cnt = 33
    stats.category["aa"].cnt = 66
    stats.category["aa"].event["bb"].value = 99

    fmt.Println(stats.cnt, stats.category["aa"].event["bb"].value)
}
```

Comment: `stats.category["aa"]` is supposed to be a map of strings to a slice of Events, but you are trying to assign it the value of 66.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are couple of issues with the code:

1. Map needs to be initialized using make function. Currently they are nil
2. Return value from map is non-addressable, this because if map is growing it needs to relocated which will cause memory address to change. Hence we need to extract value explicitly from map to a variable, update it and assigning it back.
3. Use pointer

I have updated the solution to show both updated it value returned and assigning it back and pointer.

http://play.golang.org/p/lv50AONXyU

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Stats struct {
    cnt      int
    category map[string]Events
}

type Events struct {
    cnt   int
    event map[string]*Event
}

type Event struct {
    value int64
}

func main() {

    stats := new(Stats)
    stats.cnt = 33
    stats.category = make(map[string]Events)
    e, f := stats.category["aa"]
    if !f {
        e = Events{}
    }
    e.cnt = 66

    e.event = make(map[string]*Event)
    stats.category["aa"] = e
    stats.category["aa"].event["bb"] = &Event{}
    stats.category["aa"].event["bb"].value = 99

    fmt.Println(stats)
    fmt.Println(stats.cnt, stats.category["aa"].event["bb"].value)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution it's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Took me a while to find your post for this answer, but it makes sense now

Answer (score 4):

Adding this as a different approach to the problem:

```
type Stats struct {
    cnt        int
    categories map[string]*Events
}

func (s *Stats) Category(n string) (e *Events) {
    if s.categories == nil {
        s.categories = map[string]*Events{}
    }
    if e = s.categories[n]; e == nil {
        e = &Events{}
        s.categories[n] = e
    }
    return
}

type Events struct {
    cnt    int
    events map[string]*Event
}

func (e *Events) Event(n string) (ev *Event) {
    if e.events == nil {
        e.events = map[string]*Event{}
    }
    if ev = e.events[n]; ev == nil {
        ev = &Event{}
        e.events[n] = ev
    }
    return
}

type Event struct {
    value int64
}

func main() {
    var stats Stats
    stats.cnt = 33
    stats.Category("aa").cnt = 66
    stats.Category("aa").Event("bb").value = 99

    fmt.Println(stats)
    fmt.Println(stats.cnt, stats.Category("aa").Event("bb").value)
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/d5DBifko1l)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your approach.

- You aren't initializing you maps.  You need to create them first.
- Maps return copies of their values.  So when you pull out "aa" and modify it, you are getting a copy of "aa", changing it, then throwing it away.  You need to put it back in the map, or use pointers.

Here's a working example (non-pointer version) on [Play](http://play.golang.org/p/M2jAFq7G8a).
Notice the construction of the maps, and the re-assignment back to the map when modifying a value.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Stats struct {
    cnt      int
    category map[string]Events
}

type Events struct {
    cnt   int
    event map[string]Event
}

type Event struct {
    value int64
}

func main() {
    stats := &Stats{category: map[string]Events{}}
    stats.cnt = 33
    tmpCat, ok := stats.category["aa"]
    if !ok {
        tmpCat = Events{event: map[string]Event{}}
    }
    tmpCat.cnt = 66
    tmpEv := tmpCat.event["bb"]

    tmpEv.value = 99
    tmpCat.event["bb"] = tmpEv
    stats.category["aa"] = tmpCat

    fmt.Println(stats.cnt, stats.category["aa"].event["bb"].value)
}
```